# Don't understand Linux screensaver

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

Could someone explain how the screensaver in Ubuntu and Linux Mint works. This "blank after so many minutes" or only one screensaver doesn't make sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: You would be better asking this in [ubuntu.se] over superuser